# ActionScript 3 Link to button resource using a string

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to make an interactive quiz using Adobe Flash and AS3.  On the scene, each question has 3 specific resources, for example:

> question1_correct_btn
>   question1_incorrect_btn
>   question1_background

I don't want all resources for each question to be visible. How can I enable the visibility of the buttons, but instead of: 'question1_correct_btn.visible = false', I can do something like: ''question' + questionNum + '_correct_btn'.visible = false'' ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like `buttons_parent["question" + questionNum + "_correct_btn"].visible`
I'd suggest checking that `buttons_parent["question" + questionNum + "_correct_btn"]` is not null before accessing its properties (to aviod error `1009 Null object reference`) — just in case

Answer (score 0):

You could use square brackets to access buttons, as @www0z0k suggests. However, I'd suggest you use [DisplayObjectContainer.getChildByName()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName()), as it is designed for this specific purpose: accessing children by name in a display list tree.

If the code in question resides directly in timeline of buttons' parent, you could just do `getChildByName('question' + questionNum + '_correct_btn').visible = false;`